# add reaction to a ctx.author message discord.py lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to react to a ctx.author message. What I tried:

```
@client.command()
async def help:
    command.add_reaction(':x:')
    await ctx.author.send('Something')
```

But I got that command has no add_reaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `command.add_reaction(':x:')` with `await ctx.message.add_reaction('❌')`

Answer (score 0):

As Matan already mentioned and for the future: you can get the right emote for pasting it into your code by using: `\emoji` in Discord, sending it and copy the converted text.

This text can be pasted into every string, Discord will convert it back to the regular emote.